# Android database SQLite Datatype mismatch

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Why is the datatype mismatched and why is the insertion of the row happening as (name,_id) and not (_id,name) when I call the createRecords method?

```
package com.caldroidsample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import static android.R.attr.text;
import static android.R.id.primary;
import static com.caldroidsample.R.id.email;



public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBName";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

// Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table MyEmployees( _id integer primary key, name varchar(255) not null);";

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Method is called during creation of the database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

// Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
    Log.w(MyDatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyEmployees");
    onCreate(database);
}
}
```

This is the class MyDB.java

```
package com.caldroidsample;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;



public class MyDB{

private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;

public SQLiteDatabase database;

public final static String EMP_TABLE="MyEmployees"; // name of table

public final static String EMP_ID="_id"; // id value for employee
public final static String EMP_NAME="name";  // name of employee
public final static String EMP_EMAIL="email"; // email of employee
public final static String EMP_ADDRESS="address";
public final static String EMP_GENDER="gender";
/**
 *
 * @param context
 */
public MyDB(Context context){
    dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}


public long createRecords(String id, String name){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(EMP_NAME, name);
    values.put(EMP_ID, id);



    return database.insert(EMP_TABLE, EMP_ID, values);
}

public Cursor selectRecords() {
    String[] cols = new String[] {EMP_ID, EMP_NAME};
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, EMP_TABLE,cols,null
            , null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor; // iterate to get each value.
}
}
```

EDIT : I changed the integer type of _id to varchar(255) but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: `I changed the integer type of _id ... but I am still getting the same error.` When you alter your db schema, you must uninstall your app and reinstall it. Or change your DATABASE_VERSION.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting the *datatype mismatched* error because you've created the column `_id` as an `integer` and you are trying to insert a string in that column.

Try `values.put(EMP_ID, Integer.parseInt(id));` or just pass an integer as a parameter to the `createRecords` method

I didn't understand the last part of your question about the `(_id, name)` and `(name, _id)` but if you are referring to the order not being retained inside `values`, that's because it is an hashmap.

One more thing, when you invoke `database.insert(EMP_TABLE, EMP_ID, values);` you shouldn't need to pass anything in the `nullColumnHack` parameter if you are sure that `values` is not empty.